# Alternate ways to Salesforce Integration than custom REST/SOAP development

Tags: integration, soap, rest

Are there any alternate ways or tools available to integrate Salesforce with other systems (in house + other cloud applications like Facebook) apart from writing our own REST/SOAP API callouts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of companies offering integration services with Salesforce - some examples: Informatica Cloud, Mulesoft, Dell Boomi.

Some are easier to configure than others but they all don't come cheap.